# Menu Item Click event According to Index

Tags: c#, wpf, menuitem

I have a menu item which has children menu items. When one of the menu items clicked, an event will be fired and do something according to the index of clicked menu item. I have seen such applications but in those cases name of menu item was criterion not index. I want something like this:

```
private void MI_Click (object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    MenuItem mnu = (MenuItem)e.OriginalSource;

    switch (mnu.Items.Index) // I know there is no such thing
    {
        case 0: {// do something}
        case 1: {// do something}
        // and so on
    }
}
```

Comment: Why do you need this? You can create individual `Click` event handlers for each item, or if using `MVVM`, each can have its own `Command` binding.

Comment: Because I add and remove menu items frequently.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try something like this:

```
 <MenuItem Header="_Menu">
     <MenuItem Header="Menu1" Click="MenuItem_Click" Tag="1" />
     <MenuItem Header="Menu2" Click="MenuItem_Click" Tag="2" />
     <MenuItem Header="Menu3" Click="MenuItem_Click" Tag="3" />
 </MenuItem>
```

And in code:

```
 private void MenuItem_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        MenuItem mi = sender as MenuItem;
        if (mi != null)
        {
            int tag;
            int.TryParse(mi.Tag.ToString(), out tag);
            switch (tag)
            {
                case 1:
                    break;
                case 2:
                    break;
                case 3:
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
```

EDIT:

To change the `Tag` of already created `MenuItems` you could use this:

```
        int poz = 10;
        foreach (MenuItem menuItem in mi.Items)
        {
            menuItem.Tag = poz++;
        }
```

where `mi` is the name of the parent Menu

Comment: Nice but I add and remove menu items frequently. I can set their `tag` when creating them but how can I modify the tags of already created menu items? Intention is, as a new menu item is added, its tag is zero and tags of other items should shift by one.

Comment: You could maintain a list of menu items with the tag being the index in the list and when inserting a new one update the tags in the list

Comment: Could you show me how to change the tag of already created menu item. As a pseudo code something like: `mi.Items[1].Tag = num`.